# Pagination broken at search results page

Tags: pagination, search

Common problem, yet this time I can't seem to figure it out: the pagination at my search.php is not working, it sends me to the index page the moment I click on "page #"

My search.php is set up like described by  wordpress http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page :

```
 <?php
global $query_string;
$query_args = explode("&", $query_string);
$search_query = array();
foreach($query_args as $key => $string) {
    $query_split = explode("=", $string);
    $search_query[$query_split[0]] = urldecode($query_split[1]);
} 
$search = new WP_Query($search_query);
$total_results = $search->found_posts;

if ( $search->have_posts()) : 
    echo $total_results;
    wp_page_numbers();

while ($search->have_posts()) : $search->the_post();
    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
endwhile; ?>
```

Then the pagination function in functions.php:

```
function wp_search_numbers() {
global $wp_query, $wp_rewrite;
$wp_query->query_vars['paged'] > 1 ? $current = $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] : $current = 1;

$pagination = array(
    'base' => @add_query_arg('paged','%#%'),
    'format' => '',
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    'current' => $current,
    'show_all' => true,
    'type' => 'list',
    'next_text' => '&raquo;',
    'prev_text' => '&laquo;'
    );

if( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() )
    $pagination['base'] = user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit( remove_query_arg( 's', get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ) ) . 'page/%#%/', 'paged' );

if( !empty($wp_query->query_vars['s']) )
    $pagination['add_args'] = array( 's' => get_query_var( 's' ) );

echo paginate_links( $pagination );
}
```

The pagination on index, taxonomy and other custom pages work fine.
I have tried several things, like adding:
    // Pagination fix
    $temp_query = $wp_query;
    $wp_query   = NULL;
    $wp_query   = $custom_query;
But that changes my search results to zero.
Also tried resetting the permalinks, which didn't change anything.
And I removed the **$wp_query = new WP_Query();** and went for the general **query_posts( $args );** without any change.

The strangest thing is that I just found out, it's not for all the numbers in the pagination. 
If I do a search query with a results of 15 pages:
Page 3 and 8 - 15 work, but not page 2 - 5.

Could anyone tell me in what direction I should look for the error?

Comment: Did you search the site for related questions and answers?

Comment: Hi Chip, yes, for many days...

Comment: Can you please **edit your question** to clarify what you're attempting to do? Your code looks like a search results query, but your Codex link is for a custom page template for *conducting* a search. Also, if you attempt code, please **edit your question** to include the new code, describe what you *expected* to happen that didn't, or what happened *unexpectedly*.